# mouseover, out and click event does not working on polyline?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am drawing a polygon on google map and giving mouse over and out event for polyline(only one line) on google map.
On polyline not add events.

```
function checkArea(area){

area_global = area;

  if( area.getPath().getLength() != max ){

    area.setMap(null);

    alert('Area must have 4 sides!');

  }

  else{

    areaBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for( i = 0; i < area.getPath().getLength(); i++ ){

        if( typeof( sides[i] ) != 'undefined' ) sides[i].setMap(null);

        start = [ area.getPath().getAt(i).lat(), area.getPath().getAt(i).lng() ];
        end = i == max - 1 ? [ area.getPath().getAt(0).lat(), area.getPath().getAt(0).lng() ] : [ area.getPath().getAt(i + 1).lat(), area.getPath().getAt(i + 1).lng() ];

        coordinates[i] = [
            new google.maps.LatLng( start[0], start[1] ),
            new google.maps.LatLng( end[0], end[1] )
        ];

        sides[i] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: coordinates[i],
            strokeColor: orange,
            strokeWeight: 5
        });


        sides[i].setMap(map);

        areaBounds.extend( coordinates[i][0] );

        google.maps.event.addListener(sides[i], 'mouseover', function(){   //event that fires when polygon is clicked
            if( this.strokeColor != red ) this.setOptions({ strokeColor: darkOrange, zIndex: 2 });

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(sides[i], 'mouseout', function(){ //event that fires when polygon is clicked
            if( this.strokeColor == darkOrange ) this.setOptions({ strokeColor: orange, zIndex: 2 });

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(sides[i], 'click', function(){ //event that fires when polygon is clicked

            for( i = 0; i < sides.length; i ++ ) sides[i].setOptions({ strokeColor: orange, zIndex: 1 });

            this.setOptions({ strokeColor: red, zIndex: 2 });

            lineBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            lineBounds.extend( this.getPath().getAt(0) );
            lineBounds.extend( this.getPath().getAt(1) );

            var direction = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading( areaBounds.getCenter() , lineBounds.getCenter() ); //almost working.  Need to get it better for irregular shapes (trapeziums etc)

            direction = direction < 0 ? direction + 360 : direction;

            bearing = direction < 1 ? 0 : Math.round( Math.round( direction / 22.5 ) * 22.5 );

            var roofOrientation = Math.round( direction / 5 ) * 5;

            $('#roof-orientation').val( roofOrientation ).attr('data-bearing', bearings[ bearing ] );

            if( this.getPath().getAt(0).lat() > 0 && roofOrientation > 270 || this.getPath().getAt(0).lat() > 0 && roofOrientation < 90 ) alert('The closer your roof is to facing north the poorer the electricity generation will be.');

            else if( this.getPath().getAt(0).lat() < 0 && roofOrientation < 270 && roofOrientation > 90 )  alert('The closer your roof is to facing south the poorer the electricity generation will be.');

            callAPI();

        });



        if( drawingManager.getDrawingMode() ){

            drawingManager.setOptions({
                drawingMode: null
            });

        }
        /*$('#map-draw').removeClass('active').text('Click to redraw');*/

    }

    $('#area').val( Math.round( google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea( area.getPath() ) ) ).change();

}
```

Comment: what does 'this' resolve to if you inspect in your listener code?

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(sides[i], 'mouseover', function(){   //event that fires when polygon is clicked
    if( this.strokeColor != red ) this.setOptions({ strokeColor: darkOrange, zIndex: 2 });    
}.bind( map ));
```

Within the listener function there are references to the 'this' keyword - calling functions and setting properties by the looks of the code. The 'this' keyword needs to refer to the object that has either the method or property being targeted within the listener. Otherwise it is likely to refer, in this instance, to sides[i] as the object.

Comment: that was not tested, it was just to highlight that the 'this' keyword needs to refer to the map object. Do the google docs say that mouseover works on polylines - i can't remember?

Comment: You should always provide some explanation to your code.